# Error while starting the server in a server-client program

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

Im working on a server-client program in Visual Studio 2015. Here im getting an error saying that the socketException was unhandled. The error is near 'Server.Start()'. The rest of the code is not displaying any error hence didnt post it.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class TCPControl
Public Event MessageReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)

' SERVER CONFIG
Public ServerIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.253")
Public ServerPort As Integer = 64555
Public Server As TcpListener

Private CommThread As Thread
Public IsListening As Boolean = True

' CLIENTS
Private Client As TcpClient
Private ClientData As StreamReader

Public Sub New()
    Server = New TcpListener(ServerIP, ServerPort)
    Server.Start()

    CommThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
    CommThread.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to tell us the error message, how else are we supposed to know what's going on?

Comment: FYI the `ServerIP` variable that you set to the `TcpListener` will represent what IP to listen to. Thus you can only connect to the server from that specific IP.